# Bokeh: Control colors on Donut chart

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am using Bokeh to create a series of pie charts with `bokeh.charts.Donut`.  The charts are based off of subsets of the same DataFrame, and all have the same category labels.  I want to ensure that the same categories are displayed in the same colors across the various charts, but I haven't been able to figure out a consistent way of controlling the colors.

Currently I am sorting my input DataFrames by the label, and passing the same array of colors to the `palette` property of `Donut`.  This still does not work as intended.  Code is as follows:

```
main_colors = ['#10A400','#DB5E11','#C8C500','#CF102E','#00AFA8','#82BC00','#A40D7A','#FF7100','#1349BB']


#split out youth health problems
for_youth_health = detailed_assessment_safety.loc[detailed_assessment_safety.youth_health_prob.notnull()]
youth_health_issues = pd.DataFrame(for_youth_health.youth_health_prob.str.split(' ').tolist())

for col in youth_health_issues.columns:
    newcol = 'youth_health_prob_' + str(col)
    youth_health_issues = youth_health_issues.rename(columns={col:newcol})

youth_health_trans = pd.melt(youth_health_issues)
youth_health_trans = youth_health_trans.loc[youth_health_trans.value.notnull()]

youth_health_trans['issue_text'] = youth_health_trans.value.map(map_health_issues)
youth_health_trans.drop('value',axis=1,inplace=True)
youth_health_trans.sort_values(by='issue_text',ascending=True,inplace=True)

#pie of youth health issues

youth_health_issues = Donut(youth_health_trans,label='issue_text',
                           values='variable',agg='count',plot_width=plot_width,
                           plot_height=plot_height,title='Reported Youth Health Issues',
                           color=main_colors)

hover = HoverTool(point_policy='follow_mouse')
hover.tooltips = [('Number Reported','@values'),('Health Issue','@issue_text')]
youth_health_issues.add_tools(hover)

#split out adult health problems
for_adult_health = detailed_assessment_safety.loc[detailed_assessment_safety.adult_health_prob.notnull()]
adult_health_issues = pd.DataFrame(for_adult_health.adult_health_prob.str.split(' ').tolist())

for col in adult_health_issues.columns:
    newcol = 'adult_health_prob_' + str(col)
    adult_health_issues = adult_health_issues.rename(columns={col:newcol})

adult_health_trans = pd.melt(adult_health_issues)
adult_health_trans = adult_health_trans.loc[adult_health_trans.value.notnull()]

adult_health_trans['issue_text'] = adult_health_trans.value.map(map_health_issues)
adult_health_trans.drop('value',axis=1,inplace=True)
adult_health_trans.sort_values(by='issue_text',ascending=True,inplace=True)

#pie of adult health issues

adult_health_issues = Donut(adult_health_trans,label='issue_text',
                           values='variable',agg='count',plot_width=plot_width,
                           plot_height=plot_height,title='Reported Adult Health Issues',
                           palette=main_colors)

hover = HoverTool(point_policy='follow_mouse')
hover.tooltips = [('Number Reported','@values'),('Health Issue','@issue_text')]
adult_health_issues.add_tools(hover)
```

What's the proper way to map the same categories of Donut charts to colors across multiple charts?  The other idea that I had was inserting a column into the DataFrame that mapped label values to colors, and then passing that column as an argument to `Donut`, but I couldn't make that work either.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, it turns out that when you pass an array of colors to the `palette` argument of `Donut`, the colors are associated with the donut slices based on an alphabetical sort of the slice name.  So, the first color in your array of `palette` colors will be associated with the slice with the alphabetically first name, etc.